# I am doing bench marking of Hadoop with caliper. The caliper benchmark a target system architecture

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop

What the problem is , the framework has a script which install and configure and run Hadoop on remote target system. The script is hadoop.sh , it contains
 expect script commands also like spawn etc.

When the hadoop.sh script runs it stops any previous running hadoop deamons.
Then it starts hadoop dameons through a line in the script liks

spawn /root/caliper/binary/hadoop/start-dfs.sh.

The problem here is the above command causes  all th daemons run.
But sometimes the SecondaryNamenode is running while the other time not.
Even the hadoop logs does not have any log related for Secondarynamenode 
when it fails to start. It seems the secondarynamenode start is not at all attempted to start.

The script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

user=$(echo $USER)
hdfs_tmp=/tmp/hadoop-$user

HADOOP_DIR=$PWD/hadoop
HADOOP_CONF=$HADOOP_DIR/etc/hadoop
HADOOP_BIN=$HADOOP_DIR/bin
HADOOP_SERVICE=$HADOOP_DIR/sbin

SPARK_DIR=$PWD/spark

HIBENCH_DIR=$PWD/hibench
HIBENCH_CONF=$HIBENCH_DIR/conf
HIBENCH_BIN=$HIBENCH_DIR/bin
HIBENCH_OUTPUT=$HIBENCH_DIR/report
HIBENCH_BENCH_LIST=$HIBENCH_CONF/benchmarks.lst
HIBENCH_LAN_API=$HIBENCH_CONF/languages.lst

sudo apt-get install expect -y
##### set the ssh no-passwd login #####
if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/*.pub ]; then
    ./generate_keys.sh
fi
public_key=$(cat ~/.ssh/*.pub)
echo $public_key >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

############## get JAVA_HOME which need to be used later ################
java_version=`java -version 2>tmp_001.txt && awk '/java/{print $0}' tmp_001.txt`
if [ "$java_version"x = ""x ]; then
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk -y
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo 'Install openjdk-7-jdk error'
    fi
    java_location=$(find /usr/lib -name 'java-*-openjdk*')
    java_loc=$(echo $java_location | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "java install location is $java_loc"

    echo "export JAVA_HOME=$java_loc" >> /etc/profile
    echo 'export JAVA_JRE=$JAVA_HOME/jre'  >> /etc/profile
    echo 'CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH'  >> /etc/profile 
    source /etc/profile
elif [ "$(whereis java)"x != ""x ]; then 
    java_location=$(find /usr/lib -name 'java-*-openjdk*')
    java_loc=$(echo $java_location | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "java install location is $java_loc"

    echo "export JAVA_HOME=$java_loc" >> /etc/profile
    echo 'export JAVA_JRE=$JAVA_HOME/jre'  >> /etc/profile
    echo 'CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH'  >> /etc/profile 
    source /etc/profile
else
    # java is installed 
    flag=0
    sys_path=(${PATH//:/ })

    for i in ${sys_path[@]}
    do
        tmp=$(echo $i | grep 'java' | grep 'bin' | grep -v 'jre')
        if [ "$tmp"x != ""x ]; then
            flag=1
            java_loc=${i%bin}
        fi
        break
    done
    if [ $flag -ne 1 ]; then
        echo 'You have installed java, but you still need to configure the java
        location in the /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc'
        exit
    fi
fi

############# start the hadoop service ################
pushd $HADOOP_DIR
  pushd $HADOOP_CONF
    echo "export JAVA_HOME=$java_loc" >> $HADOOP_CONF/hadoop-env.sh
  popd
/usr/bin/expect  << EOF
  spawn $HADOOP_SERVICE/stop-all.sh
  expect {
    "connecting (yes/no)?"
    {
      send "yes\r"
      expect "connecting (yes/no)?"
      send "yes\r"
    }
  }
  expect eof
EOF
  rm -fr $hdfs_tmp
  $HADOOP_BIN/hdfs namenode -format
/usr/bin/expect  << EOF
  spawn $HADOOP_SERVICE/start-dfs.sh
   expect {
    "connecting (yes/no)?"
    {
      send "yes\r"
      expect "connecting (yes/no)?"
      send "yes\r"
    }
  }
  expect eof
EOF
  hdfs_jps=$(jps)
  if [ "$(echo $hdfs_jps | grep -w 'SecondaryNameNode')"x != ""x ]; then
    if [ "$(echo $hdfs_jps | grep -w 'DataNode')"x != ""x ]; then
      if [ "$(echo $hdfs_jps | grep -w 'NameNode')"x != ""x ]; then
        echo 'hdfs run successfully'
      else
    echo 'Namenode setup error'
    exit
      fi
    else
        echo 'DataNode setup error'
    exit
    fi
  else
    echo 'SecondaryNameNode setup error'
    exit
  fi

/usr/bin/expect  << EOF
  spawn $HADOOP_SERVICE/start-yarn.sh
  expect {
    "connecting (yes/no)?"
    {
      send "yes\r"
      expect "connecting (yes/no)?"
      send "yes\r"
    }
  }
  expect eof
EOF
  yarn_jps=$(jps)
  yarn_suc=$(echo $yarn_jps | grep -w 'NodeManager')
  yarn_suc1=$(echo $yarn_jps | grep -w 'ResourceManager')
  if [ "$yarn_suc"x != ""x -a "$yarn_suc1"x != ""x ]; then
      echo 'yarn run successfully'
  else 
      echo 'yarn set up failed'
      exit
  fi
popd

############## start hibench testing ################
pushd $HIBENCH_DIR
    sed -i 's/^spark/#spark/g'  $HIBENCH_LAN_API
    # benchmarks.lst modify
    sed -i 's/^aggregation/#aggregation/g' $HIBENCH_BENCH_LIST
    sed -i 's/^join/#join/g' $HIBENCH_BENCH_LIST
    sed -i 's/^pagerank/#pagerank/g' $HIBENCH_BENCH_LIST
    sed -i 's/^scan/#scan/g' $HIBENCH_BENCH_LIST
    sed -i 's/^nutchindexing/#nutchindexing/g' $HIBENCH_BENCH_LIST
    # modify 99-user_defined_properties.conf        
    pushd $HIBENCH_CONF
        cp 99-user_defined_properties.conf.template 99-user_defined_properties.conf
        USER_DEFINED_FILE=$HIBENCH_CONF/99-user_defined_properties.conf
        hdfs_url="\/URL\/TO\/YOUR\/HDFS"
        hadoop_str="\/PATH\/TO\/YOUR\/HADOOP\/ROOT"
        hdfs_server="hdfs\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:9000"
        spark_str="\/PATH\/TO\/YOUR\/SPARK\/ROOT"
    hadoop_dir=${HADOOP_DIR//\//\\\/}
    spark_dir=${SPARK_DIR//\//\\\/}
echo $hadoop_dir
        sed -i "s/$hadoop_str/$hadoop_dir/g"  $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i "s/$spark_str/$spark_dir/g" $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i "s/$hdfs_url/$hdfs_server/g" $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i 's/^hibench.spark.master/#hibench.spark.master/g'    $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i 's/#hibench.spark.version/hibench.spark.version/g' $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i 's/ 4 / 2 /g' $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i '52,67s/12/2/g' $USER_DEFINED_FILE
        sed -i '52,67s/6/1/g'  $USER_DEFINED_FILE
    popd

    RESULT=$HIBENCH_DIR/report/hibench.report
    if [ -f $RESULT ]; then
        rm -fr $RESULT
    fi
    ./bin/run-all.sh
    if [ -f $RESULT ]; then
        cat $RESULT
    else
        echo 'The Hibench test has not generate the report, runs error.'
        exit 
    fi
popd


####### stop hadoop service ##########
pushd $HADOOP_DIR
  $HADOOP_SERVICE/stop-yarn.sh
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
      echo 'stop yarn service failed'
  fi
  $HADOOP_SERVICE/stop-dfs.sh
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
      echo 'stop hdfs service failed'
  fi
popd
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank u

Comment: The start-dfs.sh is running properly when manually ran, all the daemons run properly.

Comment: I found the problem and solution. When expect script is executing

Comment: The daemons Namenode,datanode,Secondarynamenode take long time to start. But expect time out after 10 seconds. To avoid set timeout -1 in expect like set timeout -1                                                                     spawn start-dfs.sh

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this. Actually the bash hadoop.sh script has

expect content like

spawn ./start-dfs.sh

this starts Namenode , datanode secondary namenode. But all these deamons take more time to start. expect by default timesout after 10 seconds.

So every time the last daemon Secondarynode is either started or timed out.

To avoid this in expect script use like this

/usr/bin/expect <

set timeout -1

spawn start-dfs.sh

set timeout -1

spawn start-yarn.sh

like this